# How do I turn an image into a popup with only text

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, clickable-image

I'm trying to have a popup show when an image is clicked. All I can find is how to enlarge an image. Below is the code I have but it's not working. I'm not sure which part is wrong... Am I allowed to have a table in the span tag?

```
.popup {
margin-top: 10%;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
}

.popup .popuptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 250px;
background-color: #5FACD7;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
Padding: 8px 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 125%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -80px;
```

}

```
.popup .popuptext::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.popup .show {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-websit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

<div class="popup" onclick="popup1()">
<img src="../media/hours.jpg" alt="Hours of Operation" width="300" 
height="200"/>
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Times</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Monday - Wednesday</td>
        <td> Thursday</td>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td>Saturday/Sunday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9:00 a.m. - 6:00 p.m.</td>
        <td>9:00 a.m. - 9:00 p.m.</td>
        <td>9:00 a.m. - 8:00 p.m.</td>
        <td>10:00 a.m. - 6:00 p.m.</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onClick="=popup2()">
<img src="../media/tickets.jpeg" alt="General Admission" width="300" 
height="200"/>
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">
<table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Prices</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adults: </td>
        <td>Children (5-12): </td>
        <td>Seniors/Students with ID: </td>
        <td>Adult Members: </td>
        <td>Child Members: </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$12.00</td>
        <td>$6.00</td>
        <td>$8.00</td>
        <td>Free</td>
        <td>Free</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: show a bit of your code atleast

Comment: It is clear enough but we can't see what you tried so far :)

Comment: that's the problem. I've over thought it so much I don't know where to start. I have an image of "General Admission" and I want to click on it and have the prices show up. So far.... I have the image but am not sure about the jQuery  part or how to call it in the HTML. I'm feeling very stupid and overwhelmed at the moment....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/
See Demo: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/
See: Inline HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can insert some text after the image after click;

```
  $('<span class="absolute">Test</span>').insertAfter(this);
```

And make wrap it in a div the same height and width of the image, and make it `position: relative;`
and then absolutely position it above the image.

```
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

Here is an example:

```js
$('.click-text').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).next('span.absolute').length) {
    $('<span class="absolute">Test</span>').insertAfter(this);
  } else {
    $(this).next('span.absolute').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.img-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="click-text">
</div>
```

Comment: @BillieC How's my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup {
  margin-top:10%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}


.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="http://abravmsd.com/images/ab_fb.png" width="30" height="30">
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">This is a popup text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working. I have a table as the popup and I'm not sure if that's a problem. I'm having trouble posting the code??

Comment: are you using bootstrap template? then you can use a bootstrap modal

Comment: not using bootstrap. i did post the code in the question. I updated it to show that.